# How can i render data on change?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, handlebars.js, real-time

I'm trying to build a project in nodejs as server and firebase as my realtime db and having some problems with forwarding the data to my html.

I getting the error:

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>   on change

I'm trying to pass the updated arr to html but can't find a way to do that.

server.js:

```
        const locksRef = await firebase.firebase.database().ref('locks')
        let arr = []
        //get list of locks
        const t = locksRef.on('value', (data) => {
            tempResult3 = data.val()
            result3 = []
            const numOfKeys = Object.keys(tempResult3)

            numOfKeys.forEach((x) => {
                result3.push(tempResult3[x])
            })
            result3.forEach((k) => {
                myLocks.forEach((my) => {
                    if (k.id == my) {
                        arr.push(k)
                    }
                })
            })
            res.render('ListOfLocks', { arr })  
        })
```

html

```
<body>
    <h1>ListOfHouses</h1>
    <table border="1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <th>Name And Address</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each arr}}
            <tr>
                <td id="data"> {{name}} - {{address}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="/seekKeys" method="post"><button name="{{locks}}" type="submit">LookForKey</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please check if res.render getting called multiple times frequently?

Comment: Yes, res.render getting called every time I have changes in my db